# Getting multiple Strings into an Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, toupper

I'm having difficulties with my homework. I have the basic logic down but I'm messing up. The objective is to make a receipt from a shopping list that's inputted by the user. For example, the user enters:

```
Apples

OraNgeS // also it's not case sensitive

Oranges

Bananas

!checkout //this is to indicate the list is over
```

Output:

```
Apples x1

Oranges x2

Bananas x1
```

I'm stuck. My code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner  keyboard    = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.printf("Enter the items you wish to buy:"); 
    String[] input = new String [keyboard.nextLine()];
    keyboard.nextLine(); //consuming the <enter> from input above

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        input[i] = keyboard.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.printf("\nYour input:\n");
    for (String s : input) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

I know I'll have to add the if statement eventually so if they type in "!checkout" it'll end the list. but I can't get past this yet.

Any tips or advice?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following code will do exactly what you are looking for:

```
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       List<String> inputItems = new ArrayList<String>();       
       List<String> printedResults = new ArrayList<String>();
       String input = keyboard.nextLine();       

       while(!"!checkout".equals(input)) 
       {           
           inputItems.add(input);           
           input = keyboard.nextLine();
       }

       for(int i=0; i<inputItems.size();i++)
       {
           Integer thisItemCount = 0;
           String currentItem = inputItems.get(i);

           for(int j=0; j<inputItems.size();j++)
           {
                if(inputItems.get(j).toLowerCase().equals(currentItem.toLowerCase()))    
                    thisItemCount++;
           }

           if(!printedResults.contains(currentItem.toLowerCase()))
           {
               System.out.println(currentItem.toLowerCase() + " x" + thisItemCount);
               printedResults.add(currentItem.toLowerCase());
           }               
        }
```

Comment: Yo thanks so much! this was very helpful especially for future reference!!

Comment: Cheers! I'm glad that it was useful. Just as the other comment mentioned it is good to specify which language it is.

Comment: is there any way I can contact you to help me with another problem?

Comment: Hey Corey, my email is : ali_2004t@yahoo.com , feel free to contact me.

Comment: Hi Jarrod Roberson, Would you please check it again, the issue doesn't sounds duplicate of that issue you mentioned. The title is very similar but if we go through the description then those are 2 different scenarios.

Comment: For example Case-Insensitive is not considered in that post at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [**ArrayList**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm) <-- Link.

**Array** is need to statically initialize it first before you can use it while **ArrayList** is automatically expanding when you add values on it. you can use ArrayList without initializing a range on it. Here is the sample:

```
List<String> fruitList = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner keyboard = null;
    Boolean isNotDone = true;
    System.out.println("Press 'Q' if you want to print out.");
    while(isNotDone) {
        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input Fruits: ");
        String temp = keyboard.nextLine();
        if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
            isNotDone = false;
        } else {
            fruitList.add(temp);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(fruitList);
```

Comment: This is a great start, but I would need it to print out the fruit list line after line (same way it was inputted). Also the quantity would have to be shown in the output like

Oranges x1, I'm working on modifying this code right now to see how I can add that feature. Let me know if you find out how other wise thank you!!